# how to prepare my dataset after selecting top 5k features.Original shape was (24500,56000). expected =(24k,5k)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, tfidfvectorizer

I am selecting top 5 k features from `X_train` using 
`feature_importances_` .
After getting the indices of these 5 k features in descending order, i 
need to prepare my data set  accordingly
`X_train` shape is `(24000,56000)`

```
# fit has to happen only on train 
X_train_essay_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train['clean_essays'].values) 
clf=DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5)
clf = clf.fit(X_train_essay_tfidf,y_train)

importances=clf.feature_importances_
```

I am expecting my final data set to be shape `(24000,5000)` of top 5K features

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the indices of those top 5K features, which has higher `feature_importance_` values. Use the indices to subset the features of original X_train.

```
k = 5000
ind = clf.feature_importances_.argsort()[-k:][::-1]
X_train_shortlisted = X_train_essay_tfidf[:,ind]
```

Now you can use the `X_train_shortlisted` for final classifier.